# Unknown column 't.faic' in 'field list'

Tags: php, html, mysql

When I execute my query i got an error

[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 't.faid' in 'field list'

I have a table called

app_interview with fields 'atid','atic','atname','inttotal'

applicants with the same atic are just one person.

I want to total all the total of applicant with same atic field value and divide it with 7 and save the average score to a new table called:

afnup_worksheet with field 'faid','faic','fnl_name','ftotal'

heres my current query:

```
INSERT INTO afnup_worksheet (faid,faic,fnl_name,ftotal)
SELECT DISTINCT 
  t.faid
 ,t.faic
 ,t.fnl_name
 ,(SELECT SUM(t2.inttotal) FROM app_interview t2 WHERE t2.atic = t.faic)/7 thissum
FROM app_interview t
GROUP BY atname HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT atic)=1
```

Comment: According to your description, `app_interview` does not have a `faid` column

Comment: are u sure ur selecting cols are from  app_interview table ? ur insert query says INSERT INTO afnup_worksheet (faid,faic,fnl_name,ftotal). Should't it be from afnup_worksheet ?

Answer (score 0):

You.re selecting `t.faic`, where `t` refers to `app_interview`, but according to the details you have posted, `app_interview` doesn't conatin a field called `faic`. This is also true for `t.faid` and `t.fnl_name`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, `app_interview` does not have a `faid` column